# How can I check to see if a process is stopped from the command-line?

Tags: command-line, process, ps, signals, process-management

I have the pid and I just stopped a program using

`kill -stop PID`

Now I want to continue it by doing

`kill -cont PID`

But only if it's already stopped. How would I check to see if it's stopped or running?

Comment: you say a program in the title, so you mean the name or you mean the PID like in the example?

Comment: Do you want to continue it in the foreground (grabbing the terminal) or in the background?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check whether the process is in stopped state, `T` is `ps` output.

You can do:

```
[ "$(ps -o state= -p PID)" = T ] && kill -CONT PID
```

- `[ "$(ps -o state= -p PID)" = T ]` tests whether the output of `ps -o state= -p PID` is `T`, if so send `SIGCONT` to the process. Replace PID with the actual process ID of the process.

Answer (score 5):

Another way would be

```
pid=1
status=`cat /proc/$pid/wchan`
if [ "$status" == "do_signal_stop" ] ; then
  echo "$pid sleeps: $status"
else
  echo "$pid does not sleep: $status"
fi
```

Answer (score -4):

```
ps -e | grep | PROGRAM
```

or

```
while true;
do
kill program 
done 
wait
```